# NSIndexPath getIndexes method....how?

Tags: iphone, nsindexpath

Am confused with the use of this method and the documentation that lists it as a (void) method.

"on return the index path's indexes"

where does it return anything too?

Should it not be:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)getIndexes:(NSUInteger *)indexes
```

getIndexes:
Provides a reference to the index path’s indexes.

```
- (void)getIndexes:(NSUInteger *)indexes
```

Parameters
indexes
Pointer to an unsigned integer array. On return, the index path’s indexes.
Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared In
NSIndexPath.h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to allocate the NSUInteger array of size [indexPath length] and pass it as argument. The return value will be written there. You have to release that array yourself or do nothing it was created on stack like this:

```
NSUInteger array[[indexPath length]];
[indexPath getIndexes: array];
```

Comment: Thanks to you all for excellent answers!  I get it now, thanks. I have chosen Max's answer for the solution even though all three are valid

Comment: losing the plot here?                                       NSUInteger array[[indexPath length]];
 
[indexPath getIndexes: array];

int len =  sizeof(array)/sizeof(NSUInteger);
 
NSLog(@"%i",len);  no matter how many rows I have in a given section all I get back for len is 2   ?

Comment: index path does not store the number of rows. it is used to effectively access cells. you need to use [tableView numberOfRowsInSection] for that

Comment: Yes, two indexes: one for section and one for row. If rows could be subdivided, there might be three or more indexes, but right now there are just sections and rows.

Comment: say the table has 3 sections and the middle section has 8 rows and the user has tapped any of the rows in the middle section, i presumed the getIndexes would return an array with 8 NSUIntegers that I could use to cycle through to access each cell in that given section?

Comment: to access cells you should use cellForRowAtIndexPath. Pass constructed index path (row+section). However this is not correct from the point of view of clean design. You have to store data somewhere else (probably array of arrays), it is not very good idea to access each cell to retrieve some data.

Comment: Hi, the code I am writing is to determine in any given group if more than one row can display a checkmark.  So when a row is selected I check first in my datasource is this group multi selectable or not and if it is not it then cycles all the rows in that group setting them to no checkmark and then sets the selected row with a checkmark....if that makes sense ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the next sentence explains the reason

> It is the developer’s responsibility to allocate the memory for the C array.

It's actually a pointer to a C array that will be filled for you with the indexes, so there's no reason to additionally return it from the function - you already know its address.

You can use the function as follows

```
NSUInteger indexCount = [indices count];
NSUInteger buffer[indexCount];
[indices getIndexes:buffer maxCount:indexCount inIndexRange:nil];
```

Comment: Thomas, "It is the developer’s responsibility to allocate the memory for the C array." does not show in the help I am looking at?

Comment: I have looked in the class reference here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Ah that explains it, the developer guide omits that line!

Answer (score 0):

You send that message to an instance of NSIndexPath, so getting one back wouldn't help. The -getIndexes: method fills the array 'indexes' with the indexes from the index path. So you'd do something like:

```
NSUInteger *indexes = calloc([indexPath length], sizeof(NSUInteger));
[indexPath getIndexes:indexes];
```

After that, indexes will be filled with the index values that are in indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Max, Thomas and Caleb, I have tried all three ways and cannot get anything to work, so maybe fired off the accepted solution too quick.....but probably more likely I just don't get it? I can't get the right size of the array in order to loop through it to access the required rows in my table.  I would have though that `calloc([indexPath length], sizeof(NSUInteger))` would for a group with 5 rows return an array with 5 rows with each row holding `NSUIntegr`.....or am of so far off beam it embarrassing?

Comment: An index path only specifies one section and one row, not all the rows in the table. Your table's data source and delegate work together to supply the rows for the table, so you should already know how many rows there are and have access to all their data.